# Tracking Fields in Chrony

Tags: linux, terminology, chrony

When I study with **chronyc tracking** command I got some fields and I need more description about it.

```
chronyc tracking
----------------
Reference ID    : B9E84541 (nobody.yourvserver.net)
Stratum         : 3
Ref time (UTC)  : Wed Dec 20 16:15:43 2023
System time     : 0.000761215 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset     : -0.000511070 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.001488404 seconds
Frequency       : 2.166 ppm fast
Residual freq   : -0.066 ppm
Skew            : 2.884 ppm
Root delay      : 0.041033130 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.004155959 seconds
Update interval : 517.6 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

In the example output above, can you describe and give some more details about **"Stratum** (what is the number of layers here? I'm working on a VM machine), **Skew,Root Delay and Leap"** fields (except man doc)

Answer (score 0):

BTW : The fact you are running chrony on a VM doesn't change anything to the signification of `chronyc tracking`'s reports.
[It might at most lead to extremely high *skews* and incidentally prevent chrony from setting the time.](https://chrony-users.chrony.tuxfamily.narkive.com/oT7Cv0ni/high-skew-values) This leading to what used to be a best practice :
Let the underlying OS set the time using whatever way and have the VM get its time from the underlying system.

---

**The stratum** indicates how many *hops* (*1) away from a computer with an attached reference clock we are. This computer is considered as a *stratum-1* computer (NTP terminology).
So in the details you provide, your system (stratum-3) is two hops away from the reference.
To take a nice image borrowed from comments, you know a guy who knows a guy who owns a watch in sync with atomic clocks.
Strata can range from 1 to 15. 0 being reserved to atomic clocks only accessible from stratum-1 servers and 16… reserved to indicate that the server is not currently synchronized to a reliable time source.

**Skew** is an estimation of the error bound on (~ estimated accuracy of) the *frequency* (the rate by which the system’s clock would be wrong if chronyd was not correcting it.)

- Your example reports *frequency* =  2.166 ppm. (understand that when the system’s clock thinks it has advanced 1 second, it has actually advanced by 1.000002166 seconds relative to "*true time*".)
  This is not an instant value but some sort of moving average calculated on the basis of a couple of passed measurements.
- also reported, the *residual freq* : -0.066 ppm which is in fact the difference between the last measurement of the frequency and its moving average. The maximum of the absolute value observed over time will lead to computing the skew.

The computation of these values is not trivial and understanding how they are related will require going through the source code of [sourcestats.c](https://github.com/mlichvar/chrony/blob/master/sourcestats.c) and [smooth.c](https://github.com/mlichvar/chrony/blob/master/smooth.c) in particular.

**Root delay** is the sum of latences due to the network connexions to stratum-1.

---

**(1) hop** : Understood generally : the number of devices, usually routers, that a piece of data travels through. Reduced to NTP context, it reveals the synchronization distance from the atomic clocks which are the source of the time signals.

Comment: That is not an accurate description of stratum.   A system with a hardware attached high precision clock is Stratum 0.  That system may serve  NTP  on inet at Stratum 1.   Systems that (re)serve stratum 1 data are stratum 2, and so on.  This has absolutely nothing to do with internet hops.   At stratum 3 you know a guy, who knows a guy who owns a watch.    That may be 100 router hops away.

Comment: @stevea : I agree & thank you for the nice image, I modified my answer.

Comment: Can you give more details about "Residual freq", my last frequency value is "2.166 ppm fast" in the skew field also "2.884 ppm", is there any relation about them, and where "-0.066 ppm" value is comes? @MC68020

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki : I updated my answer with the links to some source code I'm afraid you will have to dig into. As you will discover, relationships are not trivial.

Comment: Thank u for details @MC68020